# VBA : getting Listbox selected column

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, userform

I need the column equivalent of `n = Me.ListBox1.ListIndex` to find which **column** was selected by the user from a `multicolumn ListBox`.

Something like `c = Me.ListBox1.SelectedColumn`.

Does that exist ?

Comment: You can only select a row in a listbox. There is no information supplied as to which column was clicked on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple way of doing this, but with some effort you can make something work using the `MouseDown` event of the listbox, as that event includes the `X co-ordinate` of where the user clicked.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather change my `Userform` than use `X co-ordinate`.